# iDeal payment SE2700 error; invalid electric signature

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, payment

This is a specific iDeal question; I keep getting the SE2700-error eventhough my certificates are valid and created correctly. The certificate is also uploaded to the aquirer (ING bank) and i've downloaded and added the aquirer's certificate as well.

The merchantReturnURL doesn't have any special characters (http://www.04dertien.com) and the merchant ID is valid.

Is there any way the expose_php setting might be involved?

This is the iDEAL error:

```
DOMDocument Object (
    [doctype] => 
    [implementation] => (object value omitted) 
    [documentElement] => (object value omitted)
    [actualEncoding] => UTF-8
    [encoding] => UTF-8
    [xmlEncoding] => UTF-8
    [standalone] => 1
    [xmlStandalone] => 1
    [version] => 1.0
    [xmlVersion] => 1.0
    [strictErrorChecking] => 1
    [documentURI] => /DOMAIN/public_html/beta/app/webroot/
    [config] =>
    [formatOutput] =>
    [validateOnParse] =>
    [resolveExternals] =>
    [preserveWhiteSpace] => 1
    [recover] =>
    [substituteEntities] =>
    [nodeName] => #document
    [nodeValue] =>
    [nodeType] => 9 
    [parentNode] => 
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted) 
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted) 
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted) 
    [previousSibling] => 
    [attributes] => 
    [ownerDocument] => 
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => 
    [baseURI] => /DOMAIN/public_html/beta/app/webroot/ 
    [textContent] => 2013-03-11T15:56:17.834Z SE2700 Invalid electronic signature System generating error: Acquirer Please try again later or pay using another payment method. Betalen met iDEAL is nu niet mogelijk. Probeer het later nogmaals of betaal op een andere manier.
)
```

And this is the error generated by PHP:

```
Fatal error: 
Uncaught exception 'iDEALConnector\Exceptions\iDEALException' 
with message 'Invalid electronic signature' in 
/DOMAIN/beta/vendors/ideal/Xml/XmlSerializer.php:194 

Stack trace:
#0 /DOMAIN/beta/vendors/ideal/Xml/XmlSerializer.php(145): iDEALConnector\Xml\XmlSerializer->checkForErrorMessage(Object(DOMDocument)) 
#1 /DOMAIN/beta/vendors/ideal/iDEALConnector.php(287): iDEALConnector\Xml\XmlSerializer->deserialize(Object(DOMDocument)) 
#2 /DOMAIN/beta/vendors/ideal/iDEALConnector.php(119): iDEALConnector\iDEALConnector->sendRequest(Object(iDEALConnector\Entities\DirectoryRequest), 'https://idealte...') 
#3 /DOMAIN/beta/app/controllers/bank_controller.php(33): iDEALConnector\iDEALConnector->getIssuers() 
#4 [internal function]: BankController->index() 
#5 /DOMAIN/beta/cake/dispatcher.ph in /DOMAIN/beta/vendors/ideal/Xml/XmlSerializer.php on line 194
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? We're having the same issue, and it is crucial that we have it fixed very soon.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turned out that in the iDEAL v3 API - which I'm upgrading to from a previous version - doesn't allow certificates that have a validity of more than 5 years.

This (very important) detail wasn't mentioned in the PHP Integration Guide, but in the general integration guide.

See

> 8.4 Creating a key pair

in [Merchant Integration Guide (MIG) Version 3.3.1.pdf](http://d.pr/f/OyTG)